# Camel AWS SQS Cron Scheduler integration issue

Tags: java, apache-camel, amazon-sqs

Getting below error while integration of cron on Camel SQS url

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: aws-sqs://QUEUENAME?amazonSQSClient=%23sqsClient&deleteAfterRead=true&scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=0+0%2F10+*+1%2F1+*+%3F+* due to: No bean could be found in the registry for: quartz2 of type: org.apache.camel.spi.ScheduledPollConsumerScheduler
```

Below are the dependency I am using :

```
camel-spring-javaconfig (jar Version-3.0.0)
camel-aws-sqs (jar Version-3.0.0)
camel-quartz2(jar Version-2.24.0)
aws-java-sdk-sqs(jar Version-1.11.714)
```

What am I missing?:

Comment: Have u tried my solution?

Answer (score 1):

According with the camel documentation for [aws-sqs-component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/aws-sqs-component.html):

scheduler (scheduler)

To use a cron scheduler from either camel-spring or camel-quartz component. The value can be one of: none, spring, **quartz**

So I think yoo need to change `scheduler=quartz2` to `scheduler=quartz`

Comment: I tried scheduler=quartz but it showing same error message

Comment: You mean the message became: `No bean could be found in the registry for: quartz of type: org.apache.camel.spi.ScheduledPollConsumerScheduler` or it is still displaying `quartz2`?

Comment: I removed quartz2 dependency and used spring quartz dependency, Any way we found alternative to delay message by setting delivery delay property of SQS to max.

Comment: You did not understand what I wanted to say in my response but I pointed you to the camel documentation.If you read that page they say:
`scheduler (scheduler)

To use a cron scheduler from either camel-spring or camel-quartz component. The value can be one of: none, spring, quartz`. In  other words you cannot put `quartz2` where the syntax say `quartz`